# Double stitched leather shoe care

Tags: hiking, boots, gear-care

I am hiking in Meindl's double stitched, Nubuk leather hiking shoes, called Badile (https://meindl.de/product/badile-en/?lang=en) I have them for quite some years now and was very happy with them all four seasons, as long as it was not too wet. However, in very wet terrain they don't seem to hold what they promise. With other words they get wet.

I have done some research online and found that I should treat them with wax and maybe also with an impregnation spray and that I should especially treat the double stitching. In the shop I bought them, however, they told me not to do anything but put wax on twice a year and when I do so I should not touch the stitching at all. These instructions are clearly contradictory. Using wax I did not manage to get my shoes waterproof.

Does anybody know the best approach and/ or online resources for care of double stitched, nubuk leather boots?

Comment: Nubuck isn't generally first choice for situations where waterproofing is critical

Comment: When I bought such shoes, I was told to always keep the leather in good waxed condition, so that the it never dries out. This really means washing and re-waxing after every (longer) usage in wet or muddy conditions.